# variadic function cast in C macro

Tags: c

I want to get this code block into a C macro:

```
void* instance = frm_config_get_instance("inside");
int (*func)(void* inst, double value) = frm_config_get_function("comp123_work2");
int res = func(instance, 0);
```

so I can use it like this:

```
res = FRM_CONFIG_CALL("inside", "comp123_work2", 0.0)
```

this is what I was able to come up with so far:

```
#define FRM_CONFIG_CALL(instance, function, ...) \
  ((int*)(void*, __VA_ARGS__))frm_config_get_function(function) \
  (frm_config_get_instance(instance), __VA_ARGS__)
```

any ideas?

Comment: You could do that in C++ using variadic templates, but I don't think that you could do that with the C preprocessor.

Comment: Any ideas about *what?* What is the problem with the code you show? Does it work and you only want a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)? Or do you get some errors? With as many question asked as you, and such a long membership, you really show know better. Perhaps it's time to go back and review [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and re-read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Probably: Any ideas how to get it into the wanted macro form.

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` doesn't contain parameter types, it contains actual parameters. But this is generally a bad idea. You are not simulating polymorphism, since you need to know exact parameter types before calling the function.

Comment: You really want single-quotes here: `('inside', 'comp123_work2', ...`?

Comment: @alk don't know where this came from :) thanks you for the heads up

Comment: @Groo I hoped for some black-belt Macro magic to extract the parameter types - which I am not yet aware of

Comment: What is the question? What's not working and what do you want to achieve? What is `frm_config_get_function` and what does it return?

Comment: best way to get into troubles :). I would pass it as a void pointer. IMO - avoid this kind of undebuggable macros.

Comment: Initially I asked for a macro solution. I researched all the options from both answers by glglgl and Groo. On the long run I found out **option 3. Having a separate function for each parameter type** is the best fit for my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you are trying to implement means that the programmer must know the number and type of parameters of each "dynamically invokable" function in advance, and this defeats the point of having such mechanism in the first place. For example, you must know that `comp123_work2` accepts a single parameter of type `double`.

While this violation of OOP principles might not bother you that much, in practice this means you will trade compile errors for hard-to-find runtime issues. Reading an incorrect varargs value, passed to a function through a macro, is a disaster waiting to happen.

There are several approaches you could take to achieve what you are doing now:

**1. Pass parameters as `void*`**

This approach doesn't give much more compile time safety, but it's far less surprising to an unsuspecting maintainer of your code.

A common way to deal with different parameter types in C is to simply pass your custom parameters through a `void` pointer, i.e.:

```
typedef int(*voidvoidfunc_t)(void*, void*);
extern void* frm_config_get_instance(const char* name);
extern voidvoidfunc_t frm_config_get_function(const char* name);
```

And then each implementation can cast to whatever it wants:

```
int printf_wrapper(void * ch, void * p)
{
    double val = *(double*)p;
    return printf(ch, val);
}

voidvoidfunc_t frm_config_get_function(const char* name)
{
    return printf_wrapper;
}
```

And you would simply call it using:

```
void * parameter = frm_config_get_instance("inside");
voidvoidfunc_t func = frm_config_get_function("comp123_work2");
double val = 0.0;
int result = func(parameter, &val);
```

**2. Variable-args function pointers**

Also, note that it's also possible to define a variable arguments function pointer, if all your functions used varargs. Again, no compile time safety (as with any variable args function in C):

```
typedef int(*varargfunc_t)(void*, ...);
extern void* frm_config_get_instance(const char* name);
extern varargfunc_t frm_config_get_function(const char* name);
```

And then:

```
void * parameter = frm_config_get_instance("inside");
varargfunc_t func = frm_config_get_function("comp123_work2");
int result = func(parameter, 0.0);
```

But then all your "worker" functions will have to "unpack" args each time, something like:

```
int printf_wrapper(void * ch, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, ch);
    int ret = vfprintf(stdout, ch, va);
    va_end(va);
    return ret;
}

varargfunc_t frm_config_get_function(const char* name)
{
    return printf_wrapper;
}
```

**3. Having a separate function for each parameter type**

If you don't have that many parameters, a way to achieve compile-time type safety would be using separate functions for each param type, i.e.:

```
typedef int(*intfunc_t)(void*, int);
typedef int(*floatfunc_t)(void*, float);
typedef int(*stringfunc_t)(void*, const char*);
```

Then you are safe from interpreting the args in a wrong way:

```
int printf_wrapper(void * ch, float val)
{
    return printf(ch, val);
}

floatfunc_t frm_config_get_float_function(const char* name)
{
    return printf_wrapper;
}
```

Which means you have a strongly typed fn pointer after the call to `frm_config_get_xxxxx_function`:

```
void * parameter = frm_config_get_instance("inside");
floatfunc_t func = frm_config_get_float_function("comp123_work2");
int result = func(parameter, 0.0f);
```

**4. Using a variant union type like `GValue` in GLib**

This is perhaps slighly less common and doesn't provide full type safety, but it at least provides metadata which can help you throw an error in case of an incorrect invocation. The idea is to have a union of several values with a value type, so that your function can check if the parameter matches its expectation.

```
int printf_wrapper(void * ch, GValue *val)
{
    // this checks that the parameter has the correct type
    if (!G_VALUE_HOLDS_FLOAT(val))
        error();

    float f = g_value_get_float(val);
    return printf(ch, f);
}

typedef int(*gvalue_func_t)(void*, GValue *val);
extern void* frm_config_get_instance(const char* name);
extern gvalue_func_t frm_config_get_function(const char* name);
```

And then you construct the `GValue` object at run time:

```
void * parameter = frm_config_get_instance("inside");
gvalue_func_t func = frm_config_get_function("comp123_work2");

GValue val = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_set_float(&val, 0.0f);
func(parameter, &val);
```

Comment: Both ideas are good, however the vararg approach doesn't work this way. You'd either have to use `vprintf()` of to unpack the arguments for the called function manually.

Comment: @glglgl: yes, sorry, fixed.

Comment: @Groo wow! thank you so much! I understand you concerns about compile time safety and dynamic invocations. Your explanations of the different options are exceptional. I am using SO for quite some time and I can't remember such a well answered question. I hope lots of people will follow your example and turn SO into a happy place again.

Comment: @Groo Still need to research the different options more but I am no longer 100% that I am going with a macro solution. That puts me in some kind of predicament since I asked for a C macro solution.

Comment: @mark: thanks! There are often many different ways to solve the same problem in programming, so people might find this useful even if it doesn't answer the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

What you are about to do will probably not work. But you can create a "light" version of it:

```
#define FRM_CONFIG_FUNC(function, ...) \
  ((int(*)(void*, __VA_ARGS__))frm_config_get_function(function))

#define FRM_CONFIG_CALL(func, instance, ...) \
  (func)(frm_config_get_instance(instance), __VA_ARGS__)
```

and use it like

```
res = FRM_CONFIG_CALL(FRM_CONFIG_FUNC("comp123_work2", double), "inside", 0.0)
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it, but it might give you the idea.

Comment: thank you! I think this might get me where I want to be. still the compiler needs some convincing. most likely this has nothing to do with your code :)

Answer (score 2):

First, as has been said before: this, as stands, seems like an odd request.

That said, there certainly are times when there is a need to determine types at runtime. However the consensus seems to be to build your candidate functions in a special way. As opposed to making the callsite do something special.
I think the motivation for this is clear: it's easy to end up doing bad things anywhere you would invoke your proposed macro, even if it's well implemented, if the author gives the wrong args.

Suggestions/thinks to consider:

Use generated code or a macros for the defn of your functions so, you can 'lookup' your function stencil rather than need to infer it.

Most solutions of this nature, that I have come across, are from remote procedure calling. The implementations of these might help but the summary is that they  follow some variant of this pattern:

- pack/serialise your arguments into a container
- write wrappers to unpack these and call the underlying function based on some enumeration of the function.

This could look similar for you. It doesn’t directly answer your question as you still need a way of feeding it arguments but something like:

```
struct arglist = al;
int rv;

al.feed_double(0.0);
al.feed_int(4);

FUNC_MAGIC("foo", "bar", al, rv);

assert(rv != NOT_VALID_ARG_PACKING);
```

Would be achievable.

If going from A_MACRO(0.0, 4) to the feed version is possible with va_list and a function call that also understands knows the significance of "foo" is. You can use this to get back your oneliner callsite but you will need the bit of code that looks something like:

```
int pack_arg_list(struct arglist* al, const char* func, const char* inst, ...) {
    // ...
    elif (!strcmp("foo", func) {
        va_start(vl, 2); // I just knew "foo needed 2 args"
        tmp_dbl = va_arg(vl, double);
        al_tmp.pack_double(tmp_dbl);

        tmp_int = va_arg(vl, int);
        al_tmp.pack_int(tmp_int);
    }
}
```

and the problem becomes how to best write/maintain this function.
I can't think of a way that isn't a bit ugly...